# Can I use tk.Tk() again if I destroy the previous instance?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I know that using multiple `tk.Tk()` in a single app is a bad practice and if I want to create multiple windows I should use `tk.Toplevel(`) instead. But what if I `destroy` the previous `tk.Tk()` instance and then call other instance? Technically the first endless loop has ended, so I should be fine, right?

For example, I've written an application that starts off with login screen and then I move to, let's say, "mainwindow" and this is the screen the user will be watching the most often. Login screen is only a one-time thing when starting the app and user will not return to it again (unless he closes the "mainwindow" and runs the app again). Would it be more logical to call `tk.Tk()` on login window and after choosing "login" button `destroy` login window and then call "mainwindow" as `tk.Tk()`?

Technically, I could just `withdraw` the login window and create all windows as children of the login window using `tk.Toplevel` (and the flow would be loginwindow -> mainwindow -> otherwindows), but I wonder - is keeping windows whitdrawn when you won't need them again a good practice?

Comment: It is ok to create another instance of `Tk()` if the current instance has been destroyed.

Comment: For the login screen scenario, it's common to use the root window for the app, but hide it until the user logs in. You then create a temporary Toplevel for the login form.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense to call the main window first and just hide it untill user logs in succesfully - thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

#### You can actually create as many windows as you want.

This code right here does perfectly work for me. **You just create several objects from one class.**

```py
from tkinter import *

windows = []
for x in range(5):
    windows.append(Tk())
    Button(windows[-1], text='Destroy this window', command=windows[-1].destroy).pack()
    windows[-1].mainloop()
```

---

So, you can destroy one window, then create another, or even make them work at the same time.

Comment: How does this work _perfectly_ for you? You are missing `window.mainloop()`, even then your button is for the last window only.

Comment: Ok, I've just tested with the IDLE, not even in a program itself.

Comment: But to avoid the main problem which is the infinite loop `window.mainloop()`, I generally use `window.update()` which also updates the window without stopping the rest of the program to work.

Comment: This code can be rewritten to give some what a working experience, if you like I could edit to show what I mean.